# why the following javascript code still executed to line 6?

Tags: javascript

```
function Foo() {
  if (!(this instanceof Foo)) {
    return new Foo();
  }

  this.name = 'foo';     // why executed here? isn't it return?
}

var foo = Foo();

console.log(foo.name);   // foo (but i expected it to be undefined)
```

It seem that when return with keyword `new` at line 4, the codes after that will still be executed anyway which is beyond my expected, could anyone please tell me why?

Comment: It should be rather obvious from the condition that it only returns if `Foo` is not an instance of itself, otherwise it continues ?

Comment: Because `foo` is executed twice: the first time as a function (you enter `if` block) and the second as a constructor (you don't enter `if` block).

Comment: You call the function `Foo();` and get an `new Foo()` and then print the name of that instance :)

Comment: Don't understand why this get down voted.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, the first time it runs, it does indeed not execute `this.name = 'foo'`. Instead it returns `new Foo()`.

However, the call to `new Foo()` inside the `if` inside the call to `Foo()` will call the function `Foo` again with `this` initialized as an instance of `Foo`.

The key here is that there are actually two calls to `Foo`: first without `new` then recursively with `new`.